# Subquery returned more than 1 value during insert

Tags: subquery

I need help with insert data from one table to another.

Table definitions are:

```
create table reg
(id int,
 datum datetime,
 status nvarchar(1)
 )

 create table gate
 (sifra int,
  mbr int,
  datumin datetime,
  datumout datetime
  )
```

Table reg data are:

```
id  datum                    status
46627   2014-05-22 12:55:02.000   I
46628   2014-05-22 18:55:02.000   O
49875   2014-08-11 18:55:02.000   O 
49877   2014-09-11 18:55:02.000   I
49889   2014-09-03 18:50:02.000   O
```

I tryied something like this but it failed.

```
insert into gate values(
(select id from reg), (select id from reg),(select datum from reg where status = 'I'),
(select datum from reg where status = 'O'))
```

Any ideas how to manage this?

Comment: The general format is `INSERT INTO gate SELECT ...`, where you put a single `SELECT` query that produces a table of all the data you want to insert. I can't figure out what's supposed to go into `sifra` and `mbr`, so I can't write a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your selects cannot return more than one record, or else you get this error.  I dont know for sure what you are trying to do but if I were to guess, I think you want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Gate(sifra,mbr,datumin,datumout)
SELECT ID,ID,CASE WHEN status = 'I' THEN datum ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN status = 'O' THEN datum ELSE NULL END)
```